# how to add spaces between numbers of text file c#

Tags: c#, arrays

Hi I have this code to convert int multidimensional array to string array and save it in text file .. the problem is I need to change the display in the text file by adding space between each two numbers for each row,

for example I have :

12

34

56

78

I want it like this:

1 2

3 4

5 6

7 8

```
  int[,] myArray = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } }; ;
            System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter("bird.txt");
            string output = " ";
            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.GetUpperBound(0)+1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < myArray.GetUpperBound(1)+1; j++)
                {
                    output += myArray[i, j].ToString();
                }
                streamWriter.WriteLine(output);
              output = " "; 
            }
            streamWriter.Close();
```

Comment: You can simply append the string to the end. `output += myArray[i, j] + " ";` which would be okay if the array is fixed.  If the array grows you may have to rethink of how you build up the string, i.e. use a StringBuilder.

Comment: I've tested it here for you: http://ideone.com/371MoG

Comment: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); sb.Append(myArray[i, j].ToString()); sb.Append(" ");`

Comment: it works thank you

Comment: Hi @DarrenDavies great link the ideone.com never seen that before. Also, if you edit a questions tags after you answer it do the tags count toward gold, silver, bronze badges? Nothing wrong with adding tags, just curious/

Comment: @JeremyThompson - Cool :) - your score will increase for each tag in a question per upvote and will count towards bronze, silver and gold.  For instance in this question the tags `C#` and `arrays`.